# Checking the link type from a LinkIt field returns the whole path

Tags: craft3

I'm doing a project in Craft 3, there are many types of links so I installed the LinkIt plugin. I'm facing problem with this because I didn't find a method to check link type.

If I use `{{ entry.linkItField.typeHandle }}` it returns the whole path (e.g. "fruitstudios\linkit\models\Url"), not just category, entry, URL etc.

Also, using `{{ entry.linkItField.url }}` only works on custom links.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the new docs for the plugin version for craft 3: https://github.com/fruitstudios/craft-linkit/blob/master/README.md#using-linkit

Instead of `{{ entry.linkItField.type }}` you should use `{{ entry.linkItField.typeHandle }}`